# awk issue with RS in mac command line

Tags: macos, awk

I have the following text file records.text

```
IronMan
1
2
3


Batman
1
2
3
```

I have the following awk command

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\n"; RS="\n\n"} {print NR, ":", $1, $2}' records.text
```

I get the following output

```
1: Ironman
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 
6: Batman
7: 1
8: 2
9: 4
```

```
Expected output:
1: Ironman 1
2: Batman 1
```

Which is wrong. This means RS variable is not picked up and still using default "\n" as the record separator? Anyone else with the same issue? Any solutions?

Comment: You expression has several error.  You do miss an `}` after `RS="\n\n"`.  When I run it with the `}` I do not get your output, only two lines.  What do you like to have as output, what is your goal?

Comment: It's a type when I entered the question. Let me put in the expected output too.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike gnu awk, OSX's BSD awk does not handle multiple-character record separators. You'll have to try it a different way, handling one line at a time.

Comment: Are you sure about multiple-character field separators?

Comment: @jaypal it appears you're right. I could swear it didn't work last time I tried it.

Comment: @Kevin is correct, you need gawk for multi-char RS. In other awks all but the first char will be discarded.

Comment: @ooga in gawk your RS can be any regexp you like, including 2 of the same char.

Answer (score 2):

From your expression, I do get (after adding missing }

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\n"; RS="\n\n"} {print NR, ";", $1, $2}' file
1 ; IronMan 1
2 ;  Batman
```

Missing a `1` here, compare to what you like.
PS this also need a `gnu awk` do to the multiple characters in `RS`

---

When you working with record separated by empty lines you should set record selector to nothing.

```
awk -v RS="" '{print NR, ";", $1, $2}' file
1 ; IronMan 1
2 ; Batman 1
```

Comment: Interesting !!! I get the expected output when I set RS = "". But why ? I have 2 empty lines after each record, so shouldn't RS be equal to "\n\n" ?

Comment: @KodeWarrior It may be that your `awk` does not support multiple characters, like `gnu awk` does. Thats why you should use `RS=""` and no need to change the `FS`

Comment: Setting RS to the empty string is a special case that means the records are separated by one or more blank lines.